# Is it possible to configure ActiveStorage to store data on an external/custom server (not cloud based)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I've looked everywhere and didn't find anything that would suggest that options other than AWS/GC/Azure/local disk is available. In my head it would look something like [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32255#issuecomment-373287626), but instead of `host` pointing to `localhost` it would point to a server via http.

Comment: did you try putting the url there instead of localhost? if yes, any specific error you facing?

Comment: I did not, I assumed it was removed in RC2, as georgeclaghorn mentioned. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: I haven't worked on it, but if there's any error, it can be solved so asked about it. Ideally, you can put an end point and on the receiving server, accept the uploaded object and save it locally in the disk.